# DigitalOcean hosting with GoDaddy domain denying access to root directory

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I own a domain on GoDaddy and am attempting to point it to my DigitalOcean-hosted website. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- I cloned the git repo containing all of my website files from local to my DigitalOcean server.
- I added an @ record on godaddy for my domain and pointed it to my DigitalOcean IP address.
- ***IMPORTANT***!! I modified /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf with my new VirtualHost pointing mydomain.com to index.html, **NOT THE ROOT DIRECTORY**.
- I then proceeded to do 'service apache2 restart' while sshed to DigitalOcean on terminal.
- I assumed this would work and then tested it out and went to mydomain.com. Not so much. This is the error I got:

  Forbidden

  You don't have permission to access / on this server.

  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at mydomain.com Port 80

This was obviously pretty surprising given that it was not redirecting to index.html, so I manually appended /index.html to mydomain.com only to find that it gave me an identical error only I could not access /index.html instead of /.

I have done this kind of things many times before, however I used subdomain records for godaddy on an existing domain instead of using a brand new domain with no subdomains. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Brandon

**UPDATE: I tried on a test subdomain with test.mydomain.com and got this new error:**

**Not Found**

**The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

**Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at test.mydomain.com Port 80**

Comment: have you tested it with a subdomain? Other thing to try, their is a networking tab in DO that, if i remember correctly, you HAVE to use to link the domain to the droplet ip

Comment: No I have not, I will do that now.

Comment: Alright I tried that, got a new error:

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at test.mydomain.com Port 80

Comment: try this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean if the problem is with the DNS record this should be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You noted you modified the virtual host to point to index.html but not the root directory. Apache would still use the root directory (DocumentRoot) to locate the index.html file. If it is looking in the wrong location it could explain the 403 error (looking in a place that the web server user [www-data] cannot read as an example).

Beyond that, a 403 like that could be permission related. You would want to ensure the DocumentRoot and index.html file have the ownership of www-data:www-data and they are all readable by the web server itself (755 for folders and 644 for files is the norm).